# INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'.

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have an .net application and SQL Server 2005 in the back-end. I have created the xml string for the bulk insert and passing that xml string to the SP. That xml string is being converted to the table type Table in the SP with IDENTITY column. As soon as I run the code I get the following error

> INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use
>   with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or query
>   notifications and/or xml data type methods.

But if I run the direct SP with the same parameters then it is working fine. Any idea?

Comment: Try `SET ARITHABORT ON`. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100098/why-do-i-have-to-set-arithabort-on-when-using-xml-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

try setting arithmetic round abort off before trying to execute the command

Comment: For inserts on tables with computed columns, you need these set options:

The NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT option must be set to OFF, and the following options must be set to ON:

ANSI_NULLS
ANSI_PADDING
ANSI_WARNINGS
ARITHABORT
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
Try adding this before your insert:

set NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT off
set ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on

insert ...